# UICollectionView fails to provide item size

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am creating a calendar for my app, where each month is a UICollectionView embedded inside a cell of a UITableView. TableView is pinned to Safe Area of the screen, so its leading and trailing constraints are equal to 16 from left and right edges of screen. UICollectionView is pinned to ContentView of table cell.

Spacing between items and lines of items within CollectionView, as well as section insets are all set to 0. So to get 7 days in a row, I use `itemWidth = tableView.frame.width / 7`. Then I set this value as both width and height in `sizeForItem()` method of the `DelegateFlowLayout` protocol.

At runtime, all values are calculated correctly: say, on iPhone 8 screen tableView width is 343, itemWidth is 49, and itemSize is (49, 49). But on the screen it looks like this:

[image]

And this is iPhone SE result:

[image]

I tried setting layout spacing programmatically, but it doesn't help. Can anyone explain where I'm being stupid and how 7 equal pieces are turning into 8 or 6 on the screen?

**UPDATE**. I tried to calculate width from ViewController's main View: `itemWidth = (view.frame.width-32) / 7` (where 32 is sum of safe area insets - 2*16). Still with zero spacing, this resolved issue for larger screens like 8 or 8plus, but SE still shows 6 days in week and forces spacing between items. At this point I have no understanding of layout logic whatsoever!

Comment: Try using `collectionView.frame.width` instead of `tableView.frame.width`. Also, when you say spacing between items and lines are 0, are you returning 0 in the `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt` and `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt` methods?

Comment: Yes, 0 spacing is set both in IB and in code with those methods. I’ve tried using collectionView width - same result.

Comment: Looks like table view/ collection view width changes after getting the item size of collection view ? can you check around that! otherwise code should work.

Comment: Size is consistent through all delegate methods: `sizeForItem(), cellForItemAt(), willDisplayCell()`. Where else can I look to detect width change?

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: It's incorporated in a complex ViewController, and it would be a pain to pull out relevant bits. For now I set the item spacing to 5 and use `itemWidth = (tableView.frame.width - 5.0 * 6) / 7` to calculate item width. This gives expected 7 items in a row. Looks like for some reason `UICollectionView` doesn't like zero spacing.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand after 2 days of research is that dividing different screen widths by 7 may cause ambiguity as per floating point result. On a 320-point screen of SE there must be a 0.00000001 that somehow doesn't allow to fit 7 equal-sized cells without spacing.

So for me a workaround was flooring the resulting itemWidth:

```
itemWidth = CGFloat(floor(Double(view.frame.width-32) / 7))
```

This gives predictable results on all screen sizes - every week has 7 days now.